# Djangobook ch 7 CSRF

Tags: python, django

I'm reading the Djangobook and I'm on ch 7.There is actually a line that says "#todo - explain CSRF token"

When I was following the examples (I'm pretty sure I've followed them exactly), I cannot get the code to function properly.

Here is my template

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Contact us</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Contact us</h1>

        {% if errors %}
            <ul>
                {% for error in errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

        <form action="/contact/" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
            <p>Subject: <input type="text" name="subject"></p>
            <p>Your e-mail (optional): <input type="text" name="email"></p>
            <p>Message: <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my view

```
    from django.core.mail import send_mail
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.template import RequestContext

    def contact(request):
        errors = []
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if not request.POST.get('subject', ''):
                errors.append('Enter a subject.')
            if not request.POST.get('message', ''):
                errors.append('Enter a message.')
            if request.POST.get('email') and '@' not in request.POST['email']:
                errors.append('Enter a valid e-mail address.')
            if not errors:
                send_mail(
                    request.POST['subject'],
                    request.POST['message'],
                    request.POST.get('email', 'noreply@example.com'),
                    ['siteowner@example.com'],
                )
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
        return render(request, 'contact_form.html',
            {'errors': errors}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Help

Reason given for failure:
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.

In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django's CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:
 - Your browser is accepting cookies.
 - The view function uses RequestContext for the template, instead of Context.
 - In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
 - If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.

You're seeing the help section of this page because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and only the initial error message will be displayed.

You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.
```

*EDIT***************

I discovered that I can view the source code for my form and the csrf_token isn't being inserted even though I have it in my template. I looked up common solutions. Some people suggested I do this

```
        return render_to_response('contact_form.html',
            {'errors': errors}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But this doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Have you yet enable CsrfViewMiddleware in settings.py?

Comment: 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' isn't commented out I guess it's enabled. The tutorial never told me to disable or enable it. I guess its enabled by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked my `settings.py` and I see 2 middlewares added not just `CsrfViewMiddleware` -

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
...
‘django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware’,
‘django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware’,
)
```

Try adding more.

Comment: I'm using version 1.4.5 and that's the only CSRF class shown. Would it be legal for me to add those lines? I'm not sure what they do.

Comment: what do you mean "legal"? can you add them and see if it works? check this - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/

Comment: I put ‘django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware’ into my settings.py and it did not work. What I meant by legal was because I have an older version. I didn't think that 2nd line would be recognized and it wasn't when I tried to runserver. I got an error saying "no encoding declared"

Comment: Is middleware ordering preserved? see this  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#middleware-classes

Comment: @rajpy yes it is in that order!